# How to keep functions names on Next.js production optimized build? (performance analisis purpose)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, next.js

I need to keep the function names to see what is causing time to block through Chrome's perfomance panel. Does anyone knows if it's possible? I've tried to skip webpack's minification process, but the function names still got uglyfied. (eg: pSol, P2Ws, 23aj).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7494

Comment: Hey @Mellet. It doesn't. I've tried that config. The files didn't get minified but the names on the performance panel still got uglyfied :(

Comment: Perhaps enabling sourcemaps might help you debugging in prod? https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/source-maps

Comment: That's gonna help me. Thanks a lot!